# How to reduce power consumption of old laptop turned into linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, cpu, power-management, xubuntu

I'd like to turn some an old laptop into a linux server and reduce consumption while idle.

I've installed xubuntu and it works perfectly.

I've already check the BIOS and there is no WakeOnLan or Boot on power on settings. The computer is from 2009 with an Intel Celeron, 2 Cores.

My last thought, was to reduce the CPU frequency at then end of a task, and increase it at the begin (through ssh). I've tried to set manually with `sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor powersave` but it complains about not being able to set the governor, maybe because of the CPU.

I've also inspected the folder `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/` and there is no `cpufreq` folder.

The suspend mode of xubuntu works perfectly, can I use it in a programmable way to achieve an efficient idle power consumption ?

Comment: Spinning disks, or SSDs? If the former, configure the system to spin them down soon when no activity occurs.

Comment: it's HDD yes. Looks a good idea I'll try it.

And about the CPU, do you have any idea ?

Comment: No idea about CPU unfortunately. But another thing that comes to mind is removing components - if you only use the system via SSH, you will probably not need a separate graphics card (don't know what your motherboard has onboard), soundcard etc.

Comment: What is the end objective here? Is the laptop running on battery? Do you _need_ something as heavy and complex as xubuntu? Why not use Ubuntu Server since you don't need a GUI? Or a non-Ubutu system if you prefer, but anything without a GUI will be much lighter.

Comment: Good point here, it's a server that will run blender in background only. I dont know if it requires a GUI stack even without using it.

I plan to remove the battery

Comment: And why do you want to limit power consumption then?

Comment: Just to save few bucks

Comment: Um. I really, really doubt anything you can do would make any detectable difference to your utility bill. The amount of power we are discussing here is minuscule.

Comment: @Oscar re blender: you can run the blender renderer headless, no need for a GUI. Re: power: Efficient idle for a 2009 Celeron is replacing it with something else, and I don't mean that in hyperbolic way: modern embedded systems will use less power, and at current (German) power prices, *not* operating a ~ 15 year old Celeron but something more modern might pay within a year: 1W of wasted-to-obsolete-hardware that runs a year costs 3.71 €/a on average electricity prices. And: Blender?? on a 15 year old Celeron?? that's not efficient at all.

Comment: @Oscar if you care at all about energy efficiency, don't let your Celeron idle for a year to have a very slow Blender platform; instead, spin up a spot VM in someone else's data center for the blender job you have for the seconds or hours you need it (depending on how your datacenter provider allows you to bill).

Comment: @Oscar for reference: I don't like Oracle, but Oracle Cloud's "forever free" tier Ampere machines will run circles around your Celeron at no cost to you and at significantly lower CO2 cost to the planet…

Comment: I think you're right. It's kind of funny to see modern blender working on this old laptop but it's not efficient at all.